# Group policy setting to prevent asking user which encryption mode to use

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, disk-encryption, bitlocker

Asked a similar question previously: [Group policy setting to prevent asking user where to store recovery key](https://serverfault.com/questions/788499/group-policy-setting-to-prevent-asking-user-where-to-store-recovery-key)

I'm trying to enforce the encryption mode to the new XTS-AES so that if the users computer is not running the latest Win 10 (Version 1511) they cannot enable bitlocker.

Right now users get this prompt:
[image]

I want them to only be able to select the New encryption mode- I don't even want them to see this prompt. And if they aren't running 1511 they will not be allowed to enable bit locker.

I can't find a policy that seems to enforce this. Is there a policy that does this?

Comment: Make sure you have the [Administrative Templates for Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48257&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True&e6b34bbe-475b-1abd-2c51-b5034bcdd6d2=True&fa43d42b-25b5-4a42-fe9b-1634f450f5ee=True). As for not running 1511, you should just push that update.

Comment: I have the updated admin templates, the issue is I don't see a policy that controls this setting. Even if you have the update you still get this prompt- I don't want the users to even see this prompt.